# Packaging and installing bash scripts

Tags: debian, packaging

I am building a .deb package for the first time. I have two files namely, app.py and my_setting.sh which i want to package. I am able to place the app.py file in particular directory. What I am trying to do now is to run a bash script my_setting.sh during package installation by user.

I have searched but didn't find any feasible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a document named 'postinst' in DEBIAN directory. Put the command to run setting.sh in that file and build the package. You can use this link too. 
https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/creating-custom-debian-packages/

Comment: you can user chmod 755 to set permission of file 'postinst'

Answer (score 0):

This a sample script:

```
dpkg -s PACKAGE &> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "run the script"
    ./script
else
   echo "Not yet"
fi
```

Create a cronjob to check the status of `PACKAGE` every `X` time.

[Scheduling Tasks with cron and atd](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.task-scheduling-cron-atd.html)